# PHP template engine with introspection

Tags: php, twig, smarty, php-7, template-engine

I'd like to define form fields for input based on a template's variables.

Therefore I figured out that a templating engine needs something like a introspection so that I'm able to retrieve the template's variables.

Smarty just offers a list of assigned variables and as far as I know Twig just in Debug mode.
Do you know how I could solve this besides writing my own engine?

Thanks in advance

Edit to clarify: If there is something like `{{ foo }}` I want to get a string with the variable name out of the template. Is this possible?

Comment: Don't pass them as individual variables, pass them as elements in an array, then just iterate over the array.

Comment: @DarkBee: If you post this as an answer this will be the correct answer.

Comment: I don't get that - what do you mean by "introspection"? Why should a templating engine care about individual form field values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `twig` you have the special variable `_context`. This is a variable which holds all known variables inside a template. You can check which variables it hold by looping the variable e.g.

```
{% for key in _context|keys %}
    {{ key }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

You also can use this variable to access dynamic variables e.g.

```
{% set my_fixed_var_bar = 'foobar' %}
{% set foo = 'bar' %}

{{ _context['my_fixed_var_'~bar]| default('N/A') }} {# with array notation #}
{{ attribute(_context, 'my_fixed_var_'~foo) | default('N/A') }} {# with attribute function #}
```

---

Macros are an exception as they have their own (variable) scope in `twig`. This means they do not share the global `_context` variable and rather have their own. If you want to access variables from outside the macro, you'd just have to pass the `_context` to the macro e.g.

```
{% import _self as 'macros' %}

{% macro foo(context) %}
   {{ _context | keys | length }} {# 0 #}
   {{ context.my_fixed_var_bar }} {# foobar #}
{% endmacro %}

{{ macros.foo() }} {# 0 foobar #}
```

---

If you need to access the variable `_context` inside a function/filter/extension class you can achieve this by setting the option `needs_context` to `true`

```
$twig->addFunction(new \Twig\TwigFunction('my_function', function($context) {
     //do stuff
}, [ 'needs_context' => true, ]));
```

---

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/v96u6w)

Comment: Thanks for your long reply. Unfortunately I'm currently unable to get the variable names in the twig template.

Comment: To clarify: If there is something like `{{ foo }}` I want to get a string with the variable name out of the template. Is this possible?

Comment: You could check the keys of `_context`: `{% if 'foo' in _context | keys %}Foo exists{% endif %}`

Comment: But I don't know the key names.

Comment: what is you want to achieve exactyl then?

Comment: I want to generate fields for input on a custom backend based on user submitted templates without any configuration files.So if there is a field like `{{ foo }}` I want to generate an input field on my backend which knows that the template utilizes a variable with the name `foo`.

Comment: Yeah but based on what? I can imagine you want to prefix your keys e.g. `field_foo` and then `{% for key in _context|keys if key starts with 'field_' %}{{ key }}{% endif %}`